# TextView over button disappears when the button is pressed

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a problem with the app (android studio, java).

1. I added a textview over a button to style it.
2. Initially, I set **android:elevation="2"** for the textview in XML, otherwise it doesn't appear at all.
3. Now, when you press the button, the textview disappears.
4. I tried to make a **setOnTouchListener** that sets the elevation for the button to 1, so the text appears after I stop pressing the button
5. After i added the listener, **the textview does not appear only when the button is held down**.

I want the textview to remain visible at all times. Any tips? <3

```
learnButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                learnButton.setElevation(1);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLearn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/style_bg_light"
        android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLearn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/dosis"
        android:text="Button Continue"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonLearn"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonLearn"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the best practice, you need either to style the button itself or to style the text and put the click listener on the `TextView` instead of the `Button`

for example:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/learn"
    android:width="200pd"
    android:height="48dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="Click To Learn" />
```

And the file button_bg.xml to be added to the drawable folder, will contain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <ripple android:color="@color/lightGreyText">
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/static_button_bg" />
        </ripple>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The file button_bg.xml handles the ripple effect on click, and the file static_button_bg.xml contains the style of the button, and it is:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#66EFEFF4" />
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```